# How do we know that the Sun absorbs most of the radiation that falls on it?

Tags: astrophysics, thermal-radiation, sun, absorption

The sun is generally considered to be an approximate blackbody. A blackbody has to be a perfect absorber. How do we know that the sun absorbs most of the radiation that falls on it?

Comment: Maybe seeing the data here helps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight#Composition_and_power

Comment: I think that model ignores all absorption and just describes the gross spectral radiation curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do we know that the sun absorbs most of the radiation that falls on it?

1. The incoming radiation falling on the Sun is insignificant compared to the amount of radiation that it emits. So any incoming radiation that is reflected rather than absorbed will have an insignificant effect on the Sun's spectrum.
2. The outer layer of the Sun (the [photosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosphere://)) is a 100 km thick layer of diffuse hot gas. Theoretical models suggest that this layer is likely to absorb almost all incoming photons.
3. Empirical observations tell us that the spectrum of the Sun (and of other stars) follows, to a first approximation, the shape of a black-body radiation curve.

Comment: I see. So all we have is the emission spectrum, and since that matches with a blackbody spectrum, we assume that it should be near perfect absorber as well. (Also considering the fact that the photosphere is likely to absorb almost all incoming photons).

Comment: Is this the same case with incandescent bulbs? Do we assume that most of the radiation that falls on it is absorbed by the gas inside? Or is it just the fact that the spectrum matches that of a blackbody?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how item #1 suggests/demonstrates that the sun absorbs that energy?

Comment: @Curiouserandcuriouser the gas doesn't radiate, the filament does

Comment: @user253751 I was not talking about emission. I was talking about absorption. Is the  gases doing the job of photosphere here by absorbing photons that come from outside?

Comment: Emission and absorption are reciprocal - good absorbers are also good emitters and vice versa

Comment: @user253751 That's fine. What is the part of the bulb that absorbs photons that come from outside? -- This was my question. I know filament is what emitting radiation.

Comment: @Curiouserandcuriouser You know how lightbulbs are transparent, except where the filament is? If you look through one, you can see what's behind it, except where the filament is?

Comment: @Curiouserandcuriouser, The glass envelope and the fill gas play no part whatsoever in the _theory_ of incandescent light bulbs. They only are there for practical reasons: E.G., to keep the filament from burning up. For purpose of describing how it works, the filament _is_ the "black body."

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.6089 has data on the absorptivity of dense hydrogen plasma that may be informative.

Answer (score 1):

What can you see through the surface of the Sun?

There are lots of examples of things that are eclipsed by the Sun and therefore the light they emit must have been absorbed or reflected.

In principle I suppose you can shine a laser or radar signal at the Sun to estimate a reflectivity.

However in practice it doesn't matter because the Sun isn't a perfect blackbody. When we look at the Sun we observe an anisotropic radiation field arising from material at a range of temperatures. This is a far more important departure from the assumptions behind blackbody radiation than any small amount of reflectivity.

Comment: Reflectivity was the issue that bothered me. An object can be opaque even if it reflects light; it doesn't have to absorb it. But I get your point. Thanks.